# How to create and run command line scripts for cURL

Tags: java, web-services, curl, command-line, scripting

I'm am trying to test a web service that I've just written but I am not familiar with cURL. Can anyone provide some simple scripts and how to run them in windows command line?

Comment: um..I haven't asked this question before.

Comment: @Dan Other people *also* use SO, and have asked similar questions. Without really knowing anything about you want, why not just search here and the web for how to run curl from Windows?

Comment: i know how to run curl commands, im just not familiar with creating scripts for it